# Neither setAndAllowWhileIdle() nor setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() once per 15 minutes per app. what to do for alarm for every minute

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeat

Neither setAndAllowWhileIdle() nor setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() can fire alarms more than once per 15 minutes per app. I want my alarm-manager to update local log after every minute. I have tried both mentioned alarm manager but none of them works as they automatically stop after some hours. Please Help me how to achieve.

Comment: I'm using AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() to have an alarm in 5s (and then schedule itself for the 5s thereafter) and it works reliably. I've only been testing for a few hours and on one phone - so not sure how it generalises - but it looks promising. Much better than setRepeating - which completely switched off when I unplugged the phone.

Comment: Whitelisting for battery optimisation did the job for me. It worked over night every 5s. Foreground notification may potentially also do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Foreground service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)) and handler to run your task every minute. You can't use AlarmManager or WorkManager because their minimum interval is 15 minutes.

Comment: Aren't `AlarmManager.setExact()` and `AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` intended for this exact use case? The docs say, "...There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see... setExact()..."

Comment: No, you can see it in when in setExactAndAllowWhileIdle docs "when in low-power idle modes this duration may be significantly longer, such as 15 minutes.".

Comment: OK, that makes sense: The minimum interval _can be up to_ 15 minutes _if_ you abuse the API often enough to trigger the throttling logic, as the OP is likely doing.

Comment: @bracadabra thnx but main moto of the app is to work like a ghost. Forground service will leave a notification is there any other workaround please

Comment: @bracadabra but alarm app works fine even if we put alarm after 1minute they work fine. Same with WhatsApp how does it even work

Comment: I suppose WhatsApp uses high priority push messages (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) and alarm app is in a white list (https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#whitelisting-cases).

Comment: @Bracadabra I managed to get setExactAndAllowWhileIdle to work every 5s including over night being whitelisted. It doesn't get killed and doesn't get delayed either. So it may be false advertising that you can't do it in intervals smaller 15min. I know the documentation but my experiments say otherwise.

Comment: @cornelius-roemer I mentioned whitelisting in comments

Comment: @bracadabra the 5s worked even without whitelisting, it just got killed when the app went into standby mode. So it's still not behaviour as advertised.